# Copying Moving Deleting Directories in Linux with Array and/or Numerically

Tags: linux, shell

I have a large directory of sub-directories that has reached the ext3 limit. I need to copy some directories to an alternate path. I also need to remove some directories completely.

The directories are named numerically 1000,1001,1002,1003. I'd like to be able to copy and delete by number. i.e.

rm -rf (WHERE dirname<12000)

I also have some non-sequential directories such as 45698,59875,897526
I was able to pull these directory names from a database and I have them in an array.

What is the best way to copy and delete these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would copy the interesting folders first. You told that you have them in an array, maybe its better to store their names in a file? Then you cold do the following:

```
xargs -I {} cp -a {} /path/to/backup < list_of_interesting_folders
```

Then you can remove the remaining folders using brace expansion (with bash):

```
rm -rf {1000..12000}
```

Comment: The file list should contain 1 directory per line?

Comment: Yes, this would be the simplest. I also suggest to pass `-v` option to both commands, this would let you see what they are doing.